# Ionic + Electron

Tags: electron, ionic3, ionic-native, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am using electron-builder taking nsis as target for making windows installer.

electron version is 1.7.9
electron-builder version is 19.40.0

Below are the package.json build config for windows setup.

```
"build": {
"appId": "com.conveyant.dispatcher",
"directories": {
  "output": "./dist"
},
"mac": {
  "category": "public.app-category.business"
},
"dmg": {
  "contents": [
    {
      "x": 110,
      "y": 150
    },
    {
      "x": 240,
      "y": 150,
      "type": "link",
      "path": "/Applications"
    }
  ]
},
"win": {
  "icon": "build/icon.ico",
  "target": "nsis"
},
"nsis": {
  "allowElevation": false,
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true
}
```

}

It will create a win-package and windows installer, but installer will not working it shows error message 
**Error! Can't initialize plug-ins directory.Please try again later.**
[image: Screen shot of error getting at time of install]